# What is the principle of RP-HPLC?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography

Is the following statement the correct way to explain principle of RP-HPLC?

> It works on the principle of hydrophobic interactions hence the more nonpolar the material is, the longer it will be retained.

Answer (score 1):

> "It works on the principle of hydrophobic interactions hence the more nonpolar the material is, the longer it will be retained." ?

It is a very crude, first order, approximation. A philosophical then arises, what is "non-polar" material and how would we measure it's nonpolarity? One should immediately start to see problems with the words like polarity...an umbrella term which is good for organic chemists only. A good rule of thumb for any explanation is that can I measure this property? If you can't, that term is just a useless filler word.

As a matter of fact let us say you have a C18 column X, C18 column Y, C18 column Z from three different sources, and you separate a mixture of A, B, C, D, E, F, F etc, which are hydrophobic compounds in general. The order of elution on all three *may not* be the same. The reason is that hydrophobicity is not the only reason for retention in RPLC. 
See http://www.hplccolumns.org/howitworks/index.php

Despite 100 years of chromatography, it has been very difficult to predict to elution order and elution time from the first principles. People try to over rationalize chromatographic behavior. LC is still an experimental science when it comes to real mixtures.

Answer (score 0):

> It works on the principle of hydrophobic interactions [...]

That part of the statement is fairly accurate. While "normal phase" chromatography has a stationary phase that is capable of hydrogen bonding, the reverse phase stationary phase is not.

Rather on focusing on the complexity of the process, I will compare reverse phase with ion exchange chromatography, using separation of oligodeoxynucleotides (short pieces of DNA) as an example.

**Reverse phase**
You would apply the sample in aqueous solution, and it would bind to the stationary phase. Then, you elute with a gradient of increasing acetonitrile concentration. The acetonitrile competes with the solid phase for interactions with the aromatic groups in the DNA.

**Ion exchange**
You would apply the sample in low ionic strength aqueous solution, and it would bind to the stationary phase (DNA is charged negatively, so you would work with an anion exchange material with positive surface charge). Then, you elute with a gradient of increasing sodium chloride concentration. The sodium ion compete with the anion exchange material for ionic interactions with the phosphate di-ester groups in DNA.

> [...] hence the more nonpolar the material is, the longer it will be retained.

If you are trying to rationalize which of two molecules will elute first, you also have to consider the differential interactions with the solvent.